# 7zip "add" command line says "There is no such archive"

Tags: 7zip

I'm trying to use 7zip (64 bit v 9.20) from the command line, and I don't understand what it's doing.

I need to create an archive of a directory, in the same parent directory, with the same name plus the extension .zip. In other words, to perform the equivalent of a GUI "Add to " operation.

When I try to create an archive with a simple name, like this, it works:

```
7z a -r -tzip  target  directory_name.24.2016.03.14
```

But when I try to create a directory with the name I need to use, like this...

```
7z a -r -tzip  directory_name.2016.03.14  directory_name.2016.03.14
```

...7zip quits with the message "Error: There is no such archive."

Well, yeah, that's true. 7zip is supposed to create the archive, and when given a simple filename, it does. Why won't it do so with a more complex name?

Comment: have you tried `7z a -tzip directory_name.2016.03.14 -r directory_name.2016.03.14`? I don't know if it will work, I have not tested this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the result was the same.

Comment: I just ran `7z a -r -tzip  w9.2016.03.14  w9` which `w9` has some pictures in it and it worked fine. Are you sure that directory is there? Your first directory `directory_name.24.2016.03.14` does not match the second directory `directory_name.2016.03.14` you are trying to zip